# Opening Android SDK manager on mac

Tags: android, sdk

Trying to open the android SDK manager on mac, but when I get to the terminal window and go to direct to tools like it says, I don't know what to do.

These are the instructions per the site

> Mac/Linux: Open a terminal and navigate to the tools/ directory in the location where the Android SDK was installed, then execute android sdk.

And it's in my downloads. What do I need to type into the terminal to find it?

Comment: Why don't you use Tools->Android->SDK Manager in `Android Studio`

Comment: I need to open the SDK in unity

Comment: So I finally almost got it, but then I had to download JDK but then each time i execute it, it keeps telling me to download JDK.

Comment: yeah you must download JDK and configurate environment after install it.

Answer (score 3):

**For manual SDK, AVD, and project management, please use Android Studio.**

Google deprecated the **android** command.There is a temporary solution that you need to replace it with old one [There are changes in latest android sdk].Using an older version tools is  basically a bad idea .

Seems like Google wants workflow to be managed using **Android Studio.** Perhaps the better solution is to use **Android Studio**

Answer (score 2):

The SDK manager, as you said, is located in the tools directory of the Android SDK in its installed location. So as per your given information it should be like this:

```
~/Downloads/Android/sdk/tools/
```

The filename of the SDK manager is an executable named "android", so cd into the directory and run ./android and you should be good to go.

Answer (score 1):

The "android" command is now deprecated. 
For manual SDK, AVD, and project management, please use Android Studio. 
For command-line tools, use tools/bin/sdkmanager and tools/bin/avdmanager

Answer (score 1):

As Android Studio 3, the android command is deprecated. So, developers should use Android SDK which has been provided in Android Studio.

```
Tools > Android > SDK Manager
```

or for command-line usage,
- on MAC

```
~/Library/Android/sdk/tools/bin/
```

- on Linux

  /Path/To/SDK/tools/bin/

then run sdkmanager.