# Android Studio 2.2 can not launch standalone SDK Manager

Tags: android, sdk, launch, android-studio-2.2, android-sdk-manager

I just updated my Android Studio to version 2.2 and now I want to update a few sdk tools and trying to launch standalone sdk manager but it is not being opened and no error message is being displayed when I click on it.[image]

Also, I tried to look in finder for Android SDK Manager .exe its not there What is the reason of it. Anyone facing this issue? I also reinstalled android studio and tried to launch sdk manager after restarting studio but it is not working. 
Here is my finder screenshot.

[image]

Kindly help. I am stuck in this. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: from this link, it says that your SDK Manager is named "android" in your tools dir. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34866430/opening-android-sdk-manager-on-mac

Comment: But It too does not open sdk manager it just opens terminal window. I can open it after running commands but there must be some solution to launch it from android studio or even from tools directory without running command. Thanks

Comment: ok. first, check in terminal if you can execute `<install dir>/Android/sdk/tools/android`.

Comment: Go to SDK->Tools->Right click on "android" and run as administrator it's open two window 1.terminal and 2. SDK Manager.

Answer (score 1):

I have also faced the same problem few days back and I end up with the solution that to use android SDK manager first we need to make sure that java jdk must be install in our system.
I am using ubuntu so i m about to give solution for the same

go to Terminal

copy paste the following line

javac -version

now it will end up with something like this as you see in the following image

[image]

choose appropriate package as i choose openjdk-8-jdk-headless

and type in terminal as

sudo apt install openjdk-8-jdk-headless

now it will take 2-3 mins and thereafter your Luanch Standalone SDK Manager button will work

and for Windows users you need to set Path for your java jdk then your Launch Standalone SDK Manager button will work

Answer (score 0):

This is what i did to solve the problem:

went to https://dl.google.com/android/android-sdk_r24.0.2-windows.zip and downloaded that sdk tools.

Extracted the file in one of the location of my choice.

Copied the SDK Manager.exe from the extracted file.

Went to the location where the original SDK Manager.exe was and replaced it with the one downloaded.

Went back to android studio and started SDK Manager, boom! SDK Manager launched perfectly. :)

NOTE: I replace all the file that included in downloaded file and leave the other remaining file of the SDK folder as it is:)